# Why was the list of closers removed when a question is closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

They used to tell us who voted to close...

I had a question that I answered closed a couple of hours afterwards.
Here: [Handheld oscilloscope for saving waveform in memory](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487719/handheld-oscilloscope-for-saving-waveform-in-memory/487741?noredirect=1#comment1241146_487741)

While the OP did detail the kind of things he was looking, to me the question was what prohibited a low end scope from implementing a feature such as data logging (at a high resolution).

At no point did he ask for a scope to do it.

What he did ask was: "I wonder why I have found none with this capability, some difficulties with this approach?"

Not shopping in my mind... (Ok, maybe shopping, but the kind I feel belongs here, i.e. why is this feature expensive to include.  In my mind you can learn from something like that.)

Answer (score 3):

It's now only visible to the author, and those that have unlocked the close vote privilege.

Answer (score 1):

So people don't retaliate, if you wan't to get a question reopend then edit the question and bring it up to the standards of the site, then nominate it for reopening.